# Laravel: Post Category Not Updating

Tags: php, laravel, controller, categories, laravel-7

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to update my Post.

The title, the description, the content, the image and the date is updating. However, the category is not updating.

I have created a relation between the category and the post.

**postCreateUpdate.blade.php**

```
   <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="category">Category</label>
                    <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
                        @foreach ($categories as $category)
                        <option value="{{ $category->id }}" 
                            @if (isset($posts))
                                @if($category->id == $posts->category_id)
                                selected
                                @endif
                            @endif

                            >
                        {{ $category->name }}
                        </option>
                        @endforeach

                    </select>
                </div>
```

**PostController.php**

```
  public function update(UpdatePostRequest $request, Post $post)
    {
        $data = $request->only(['title','description','content','published_at','category']);

        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $image = $request->image->store('posts');
            $post->deleteImage();


            $data['image'] = $image;
        }


        $post->update($data);

        session()->flash('success','Post Updated Successfully');

        return redirect(route('post.index'));

    }
```

I have added the files to github.
Here is the link: https://github.com/remanbala/LaravelCMSExample

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a column named 'category_id' in your posts table, but in this scenario you are trying to set an id on a column named 'category' which probably doesn't exist in your table.

Try changing 'category' to 'category_id':

**postCreateUpdate.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <select name="category_id" id="category_id" class="form-control">
        @foreach ($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}" 
            @if (isset($posts))
                @if($category->id == $posts->category_id)
                selected
                @endif
            @endif
         >
             {{ $category->name }}
         </option>
         @endforeach
     </select>
 </div>
```

**PostController.php**

```
public function update(UpdatePostRequest $request, Post $post)
{
    $data = $request->only(['title','description','content','published_at','category_id']);

    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        $image = $request->image->store('posts');
        $post->deleteImage();
        $data['image'] = $image;
    }

    $post->update($data);

    session()->flash('success','Post Updated Successfully');

    return redirect(route('post.index'));
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and upon trying to update, it told that the category field is required.

Comment: @RamanBala thats's because you are validating your request, and demanding a 'category' field, you must also update that validation to 'category_id' in your `UpdatePostRequest`.

Comment: data = $request->only(['title','description','content','published_at','category_id']); 
This line of code is requesting from the form isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but the before that you are validating all that form data in your `App\Http\Requests\UpdatePostRequest.php` file, so in there you must also update 'category' to 'category_id'.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from my side, what I have understood so far is that I have gone through your repository and I found the CreatePostsTable migration file-

```
class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->text('content');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

See, the problem? There is no `category_id` field there. If you already ran the migration, then probably, the posts table would not have the field `category_id`. Hope, it will help you. Thank you.

Comment: I have the migration AddColumnIdColumnToPostsTable in the migration files. The category_id is in there and is migrated.